# Object is not a constructor in React Native when using pubnub-react

Tags: react-native, constructor, pubnub

I am trying to integrate pubnub-react in react native.
Here's my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PubNubReact from 'pubnub-react';
import {key1,key2} from '../config.js

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.pubnub = new PubNubReact({
      publishKey: key1,
      subscribeKey: key2
    });
    this.pubnub.init(this)
  }
  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

This is throwing this error:

`[[TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _pubnubReact.default')]][1]`

Version of react native is 0.62.1

Comment: Which version of PubNub SDK are you using (point me to a link on PubNub's site, please and indicate version number)? Can you provide more of  you code?

Comment: I'm looking at a [PubNub blog from 2017 about PubNub React Native](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/pubnub-react-native-basics-pub-sub-history-gelocation-presence/) and I see one major difference. Your code: `export default class extends Component {`. PN blog code: `export default class App extends Component { `. Do you just need to add `App` after class?

Comment: adding 'App' after class won't make any changes. But i gave it a try and error is still same. pubnub version is 4.27.4  and pubnub-react version is 2.0.0. Btw the link i am refering to is [link](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-geo-tracking-app-react-native/)

Comment: I solved the issue using pubnub instead of using pubnub-react. I refered to this [link](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) which resolved my issue

Comment: Great to hear that you resolved this. If you can, post an answer to your question here to earn more reputation points.

Comment: I am also confused about it. Tried pubnub: 4.27.5 and pubnub-react: 2.0.0 on react: 16.9.0 and react-native: 0.61.5. I see the same error.

Comment: @AnshikaAgrawal did you manage to make it work using Nodejs example with React Native Push notifications?

Comment: pubnub didn't work well as it raised [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142691/pubnub-listeners-not-working-in-react-native) issue in which listeners were not working as i expected it to work. So i used socket.io with nodejs instead of pubnub.

Comment: @ErikRybalkin i would refer u to use "react-native-push-notification" npm package to implement push notification bcoz i used it and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

A PubNub engineer should be posting answer soon.

---

**Alternative solution**
Posting this on Anshika Agrawal's behalf so that this post has an answer.

> I solved the issue using pubnub instead of using pubnub-react. I referred to [this link](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) which resolved my issue – Anshika Agrawa

Comment: Anshika Agrawa, if you post an answer, I will remove this one so you can get the credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using pubnub instead of using pubnub-react. I refered to this link https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk which resolved my issue

Comment: Can you share or post some code here or provide a small description here as direct link answers are not accepted on SO.