# pubnub listeners not working in react-native

Tags: react-native, pubnub

I am working on realtime geolocation-tracking app using pubnub and react-native-maps in react-native. `pubnub.publish()` is working when called inside `Geolocation.getCurrentLocation()` and `Geolocation.watchPosition()` inside `componentDidMount()`.

**Here is the code which is worlking fine:**

```js
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          if (this.state.allowsGPS) {
            this.pubnub.publish({
              message: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                from: '1'
              },
              channel: "location_tracker_channel"
            }, () => console.log("publish 1"))
            let users = this.state.users;
            let tempUser = {
              uuid: this.pubnub.getUUID(),
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude
            }
            users.set(tempUser.uuid, tempUser)
            this.setState({
              users,
              currentLocation: position.coords
            })
          }
        },
        error => console.log("error in currentPos:", error),
        {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          distanceFilter: 0.1
        }
      )

      Geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
          this.setState({
            currentLocation: position.coords
          })
          if (this.state.allowsGPS) {
            console.log("published:", position.coords)
            this.pubnub.publish({
              message: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                from: '2'
              },
              channel: "location-tracker-channel"
            }, () => console.log("publish 2"))
          }
        },
        err => console.log("err in geolocation:", err),
        {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          distanceFilter: 0.1
        }
      )
    } else {
      console.log("location permission denied")
    }
  }
```

But its not working in `componentDidUpdate()` which is supposed to publish `{hideUser:true}` when `this.state.allowsGPS` is `true` and publish users info when its `false`. Although in logs its printing `publish 4` and `publish 3`, respectively, but its not listening to any such messages.

**Here is the code not working:**

```js
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.allowsGPS != this.state.allowsGPS) {
      if (this.state.allowsGPS) {
        let users = this.state.users;
        let tempUser = {
          uuid: this.pubnub.getUUID(),
          latitude: this.state.currentLocation.latitude,
          longitude: this.state.currentLocation.longitude,
          image: this.state.currentPicture,
          username: this.state.username,
          from: '3'
        }
        users.set(tempUser.uuid, tempUser);
        this.pubnub.publish({
          message: tempUser,
          channel: "location_tracker_channel",
        }, () => console.log("publish 3"))
        this.setState({
          users
        })
      }
      else {
        let users = this.state.users;
        let uuid = this.pubnub.getUUID();

        users.delete(uuid);
        let tempMssg = { hideUser: true, from: '4' }
        this.pubnub.publish({
          message: tempMssg,
          channel: "location_tracker_channel",
        }, () => console.log("publish 4"))

        this.setState({
          users
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**Here is my full code:**

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    this.setUpApp();
  }

  async setUpApp() {
    this.pubnub.addListener({
      message: mssg => {
        let users = this.state.users;
        if (mssg.message.hideUser) {
          users.delete(mssg.publisher);
          this.setState({
            users
          })
        } else {
          let oldUser = this.state.users.get(mssg.publisher);
          let newUser = {
            uuid: mssg.publisher,
            latitude: mssg.message.latitude,
            longitude: mssg.message.longitude
          }
          if (mssg.message.message) {
            setTimeout(mssg.publisher, this.clearMessage, 5000, mssg.publisher);
            newUser.message = mssg.message.message
          } else if (oldUser) {
            newUser.message = oldUser.message
          }
          users.set(newUser.uuid, newUser);
          this.setState({
            users
          })
        }
      }
    })
    this.pubnub.subscribe({
      channels: ["location-tracker-channel"],
      withPresence: true
    })

    let granted;
    if (Platform.OS == "android") {
      granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Location Permissions',
          message: 'LocationTracker needs to access your location',
          buttonNegative: 'NO',
          buttonPositive: 'YES'
        }
      )
    }
    if (granted == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || Platform.OS == 'ios') {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          if (this.state.allowsGPS) {
            this.pubnub.publish({
              message: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                from: '2'
              },
              channel: "location_tracker_channel"
            }, () => console.log("publish 1"))
            let users = this.state.users;
            let tempUser = {
              uuid: this.pubnub.getUUID(),
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude
            }
            users.set(tempUser.uuid, tempUser)
            this.setState({
              users,
              currentLocation: position.coords
            })
          }
        },
        error => console.log("error in currentPos:", error),
        {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          distanceFilter: 0.1
        }
      )

      Geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
          this.setState({
            currentLocation: position.coords
          })
          if (this.state.allowsGPS) {
            console.log("published:", position.coords)
            this.pubnub.publish({
              message: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                from: '2'
              },
              channel: "location-tracker-channel"
            }, () => console.log("publish 2"))
          }
        },
        err => console.log("err in geolocation:", err),
        {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          distanceFilter: 0.1
        }
      )
    } else {
      console.log("location permission denied")
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.allowsGPS != this.state.allowsGPS) {
      if (this.state.allowsGPS) {
        let users = this.state.users;
        let tempUser = {
          uuid: this.pubnub.getUUID(),
          latitude: this.state.currentLocation.latitude,
          longitude: this.state.currentLocation.longitude,
          image: this.state.currentPicture,
          username: this.state.username,
          from: '3'
        }
        users.set(tempUser.uuid, tempUser);
        this.pubnub.publish({
          message: tempUser,
          channel: "location_tracker_channel",
        }, () => console.log("publish 3"))
        this.setState({
          users
        })
      }
      else {
        let users = this.state.users;
        let uuid = this.pubnub.getUUID();

        users.delete(uuid);
        let tempMssg = { hideUser: true, from: '4' }
        this.pubnub.publish({
          message: tempMssg,
          channel: "location_tracker_channel",
        }, () => console.log("publish 4"))

        this.setState({
          users
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**Libraries used:**
 * pubnub version-4.27.4
 * react-native version-'0.62.1'
 * react-native-maps version='0.27.1'

Comment: Without being able to run your code, the most likely issue is that your `addListener` code is not in scope. Make sure that this code is at the app scope so that it is always "alive" and never null and garbage collected. If that is not the issue I would recommend [enabling PubNub JavaScript logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and submit the logs to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com). But do let me know if the scope is the issue or not and if you have any errors you can report.

Comment: `addListener` should be called for once thats why it is added in `componentDidMount` which prevents from creating multiple listeners everytime component re-renders after state change. I tried to put defination of `setUpApp()` inside `componentDidMount` but didn't change anything. The issue is not related with scope because i tried to publish a mssg inside the same scope, but didn't work