# TypeError Object is not a constructor (evaluating new_pubnubReact.default')

Tags: react-native, pubnub

I am new to react native and am trying to create push notifications for android.

I am using the following tutorial from PubNub.

[PubNub tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications-ios-android/)

When I run my app in the android studio emulator after finishing the tutorial I get the following error.

[image: error]

Not quite sure what it means of how to fix it as when I google the problem nothing  comes up.

Here is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
    import PushNotificationIOS from 'react-native';
    import PubNubReact from 'pubnub-react';

    const PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');

    export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pubnub = new PubNubReact({
        publishKey: 'YOUR_PUBNUB_PUBLISH_KEY_HERE',
        subscribeKey: 'YOUR_PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY_HERE'
    });
    this.pubnub.init(this);
    PushNotification.configure({
      // Called when Token is generated.
      onRegister: function(token) {
          console.log( 'TOKEN:', token );
          if (token.os == "ios") {
            this.pubnub.push.addChannels(
            {
              channels: ['notifications'],
              device: token.token,
              pushGateway: 'apns'
            });
            // Send iOS Notification from debug console: {"pn_apns":{"aps":{"alert":"Hello World."}}}
          } else if (token.os == "android"){
            this.pubnub.push.addChannels(
            {
              channels: ['notifications'],
              device: token.token,
              pushGateway: 'gcm' // apns, gcm, mpns
            });
            // Send Android Notification from debug console: {"pn_gcm":{"data":{"message":"Hello World."}}}
          }  
      }.bind(this),
      // Something not working?
      // See: https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043605-how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues-
      // Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received.
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
        // Do something with the notification.
        // Required on iOS only (see fetchCompletionHandler docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/pushnotificationios)
        // notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      },
      // ANDROID: GCM or FCM Sender ID
      senderID: "sender-id",
  });
}
    }
```

Comment: Does this post answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080350/object-is-not-a-constructor-in-react-native-when-using-pubnub-react

Comment: I have ready seen this post and did as it said but sadly it didn't work

Comment: Thanks for confirming. But is your issue different from that one? I just need to know if I should direct the attention of a PubNub engineer at one the other or both.

Comment: What version of `pubnub-react` are you using?

Comment: @AreWojciechowski - according to the tutorial followed, it should be pubnub-react@2.0.0

Comment: it's version 2.0.0

Comment: my issues is the same as what was posted in the answer shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pubnub-react` library has been completely changed in version `2.0.0`. It no longers includes `pubnub` JavaScript SDK by default so you have to install it as well.

[Here is the link](https://github.com/pubnub/react) to new PubNub React repository, and in the `README.md` file you can find examples on how to use it.

---

If you want to use the older version that is compatible with the tutorial/blog post you may be reading, please install the older version of the PubNub React SDK like so:

```
$ npm install pubnub-react@1
```

---

To summarize the changes, `pubnub-react` now uses Context and Hooks API to propagate PubNub instance deep into the children tree.

### Provider

You need to include the provider somewhere top in the component tree.

```
import React from 'react'
import PubNub from 'pubnub'
import { PubNubProvider } from 'pubnub-react'

const pubnub = new PubNub({}) // PubNub configuration

export const App = () => {
    return <PubNubProvider client={pubnub}>
        <Child />
    </PubNubProvider>
}
```

### Consumer

To use the PubNub instance somewhere else, you can now just use the `usePubNub` hook.

```
import { usePubNub } from 'pubnub-react'

export const Child = () => {
    const pubnub = usePubNub()
    
    return <div>I am using PubNub!</div>
}
```

Comment: if this is the case they would need to update their documents

Comment: So, @becky, did the answer solve the issue for you?