# PubNub React-Native JS SDK Version 2 Stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pubnub

Hi I'm trying to use the new pubnub react-native sdk in my stateful component but i keep getting:

"TypeError Object is not a constructor (evaluating new_pubnubReact.default')"

My component is structured like this :

```
    class testComponent extends Component{
       state={
        .....
       }
       pubnub = new PubNubReact({
      publishKey: "***",
      subscribeKey: "****"
       });
 
... 

}
```

How should i proceed to use the SDK without having to use a constructor and without having to switch the whole component into a functional component?

Comment: I got around it using the nodeJS PubNub sdk only but not sure if it's the best way to go

Comment: This question has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61362706/2044286. If you find that it solves your problem, please upvote it so other folks can find it in the future.